# “Touch anywhere to take photo” Android camera app

Tags: android, camera

What I liked most about my old Moto G3 was the "touch anywhere (except the focus circle) to take photo" on its camera app. If you are riding a bicycle, it was so easy to take out your phone with one hand, double press the power button to open the camera app, touch anywhere on the screen (except the focus circle) to take a photo, press the power button to put the phone to sleep, and put the phone back in your pocket. The entire process was lightning quick.

When I started using an iPhone while riding a bicycle, things got difficult. My thumb frequently got sprained trying to reach the circle shutter icon. Also, the few milliseconds you need in order to aim for the circle (as opposed to touching anywhere on the screen) you end up missing your subject. Pressing the volume button for shutter, using one hand while riding a bicycle, makes your hand shake slightly so it's a bad solution. The whole process to take a photo, while riding a bicycle, became time consuming and painful.

I plan to upgrade to a OnePlus 8 Pro. What Android camera apps allow you to take photos by touching anywhere on the screen? The default Moto Camera app shows up in the Play store only if you are logged in using a Moto phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had same question/issue. New phone , not a Moto.

I found SILENT CAMERA by Peace and can change to SINGLE TOUCH in Settings (it focuses and snaps.photo anywhere you touch screen) and can turn it on/off   They have some great other features too.
I am not a rep or affiliated w them at all.

Comment: Welcome Lori, and thank you for your helpful answer!  Can you add a link to the app in your answer?   Thanks, and again, welcome!